# Best place for data validation: property vs constructor

Tags: c#, validation, constructor

Suppose I have a Book class that contains the number of pages. Where should I validate the data, in the property or in the constructor? These two options look the same to me, except the second option looks cleaner.

Property

```cs
class Book
{
    private int _pageCount;
    
    public int PageCount
    {
        get => _pageCount;
        set => _pageCount = value > 300 ? 0 : value;
    }

    public Book(int pageCount)
    {
        PageCount = pageCount;
    }
}
```

Constructor

```cs
class Book
{
    public int PageCount { get; set; }

    public Book(int pageCount)
    {
        PageCount = pageCount > 300 ? 0 : pageCount;
    }
}
```

I've read in similar questions that mandatory data should be validated in the constructor and optional data in the property. So it seems that in this example we should validate in the constructor or am I missing something?

Comment: What about `var book = new Book(200); book.PageCount = 500000;` Also failing silently is dangerous as you will get unexpected side effects any time a parameter value does not meet what is expected or what the application can handle. A better implementation would be to throw an `ArgumentException` or one of the derived types.

Comment: _am I missing something?_: It seems that you haven't considered what will happen if someone sets the value of the property without using the constructor.

Comment: Good point. But i believe in this example we could safely use init instead of set because the number of pages in the book should not change after creation.

Comment: Well, think about *business operations*, not objects. In other words think about how you *use* the book rather than the book itself. The book usually doesn't contain 100000 pages not merely because its a book but because of the way it is created and used by other objects. So it is only logical to move the validation outside of it to that *other* objects..

Comment: This may not be relevant as your question may just be for example purposes. But it seems a little odd that I would tell the book how many pages it would have. I feel like this should only be a question I could ask the book and not tell the book. The book would allow pages to be added and then I could simple ask the book how many pages it has.

Comment: _"mandatory data should be validated in the constructor"_, this is accurate but don't add a constructor parameter because you want to validate it in the constructor, add a constructor parameter because the object requires it so it can be initialized in a valid state.

Comment: Did you try to step through your *Property* code example with a debugger?

Comment: Seek to understand the differences between them. Don't ask which is _best_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt if you should *silently* change given value, i.e.:

```
// Just an innocent creation, no complains from the constructor 
Book LeoTolsoiWarAndPeace = new Book(1000);

...
// A lot of code here
...

// 0 - what??? I've provided 1000! Mistery to be solved ...
Console.WriteLine(LeoTolsoiWarAndPeace.PageCount);
```

When validating you usually either accept the value or throw exception
(class instance doesn't know what to do with invalid value, say `-123` -
should it be `123`, `0` should it be corrected at all):

```
class Book
{
    private int _pageCount;
    
    public int PageCount
    {
        get => _pageCount;
        set => _pageCount = value >= 0 || value <= 300 
          ? value
          : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), 
              "page count should be in 0 .. 300 range");
    }

    public Book(int pageCount)
    {
        PageCount = pageCount;
    }
}
```

Now invalid input is *easy to trace*:

```
// Bump! ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown
// No mistery here: I know that the routine doesn't support huge books
Book LeoTolsoiWarAndPeace = new Book(1000);

...
```

Please, note that validation should not depened on how you create an instance,
that's why in your case it should not be in the constructor. Just compare:

```
// 123456 is invalid and it will be changed into 0
Book demo1 = new Book(123456);

// Here, constructor will get 0, no validation will be performed
// And then invalid 123456 will be assigned to PageCount
Book demo2 = new Book(default) {
  PageCount = 123456;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

According to SOLID principle (specifically S - single responsibility) an object should not be responsible for more than one business operation.

Think about it for a second, books don't know how to validate themselves in real life. Books contain pages with text that is written according to certain standards and regulations.

A 1M page book is a theoretical possibility but not for real world writers, typographies and so on.

Depending on your needs you might want to *change the way* how you allow books to be created or *use validator*. For instance this is a static class with an extension method:

```
public static class BookValidationExtensions
{
   public static bool Validate(this Book book)
   {
      return book.PageCount <= 300;
   }
}
```

Now create a book and use it:

```
Book book = new Book(10000);

if (!book.Validate())
{
   // do sth, for example:
   throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Or you could encapsulate the logic of how the book is created using the Factory pattern:

```
public class BookFactory
{
   public Book Create(int pageCount)
   {
      if (pageCount > 300)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException(nameof(pageCount));
      }
      return new Book(pageCount);
   }
}
```

And use it:

```
Book book = new BookFactory().Create(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two implementations are very different.

Ordinarily you need data validation in *both* a constructor and a setter. That is, you need to validate incoming data wherever you accept it.

If you will not change the property after constructing the object, you can code it so it only has a getter, not a setter. Then you don't need a validator in the setter.

```cs
class Book
{
    public int PageCount { get; }   /* no set operation here */

    public Book(int pageCount)
    {
        PageCount = pageCount > 300 ? 0 : pageCount;
    }
}
```

But this isn't, strictly speaking, a validator. A true validator rejects bad data by alerting its caller, perhaps by throwing an exception. Your code transforms its data. From your code it looks like `301` is a perfectly valid page count, but that your object represents it as `0`. That might, or might not, be an important business rule for your application. But it's a good idea to be suspicious of injective rules, that is rules which map many data values into fewer data values. Those sorts of rules lose data details, often considered harmful.

**Pro tip**  It's good practice to write your code to *implement* assumptions like "never set this property after constructing the object". That way your code will be less likely to be misused in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Property and Constructor both are different things, Constructors are basically used to initialize the class members, and properties are used to read the private fields, they use accessors through which we can read, write or change the values of the private fields.

Now just consider you have Some fields in class and you want to assign some values to them, then you can initialize in the inside constructor and assign some values.

So if you want to validate anything then validate it inside Constructor, validating it inside Property is not a good option cause every time you'll call that property it'll validate it and if you'll do it inside the constructor it'll be validated only once when that class will be called.